# Не настраивается pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql

Не могу получить доступ к базе данных. При этом на другой виртуальной машине, на другом айпи, все настроено и подключение есть.

Файл pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD   
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
hostssl all     all     192.168.255.170/32      md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Вот что выдает pgadmin III:

> FATAL: password authentication failed for user "geonode" FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.255.170", user "geonode", database "geonode", SSL off

P.S. postgres 9.3. + postgis

Comment: Что будет, если заменить `hostssl` на `host`? Какое значение у `listen_addresses` в `postgresql.conf`? Перезапускали сервер после редактирования `pg_hba.conf`?

Comment: Прошу прощения, не то окно смотрел. Изменение `hostssl` выдало ошибку неправильный пароль у пользователя. Изменил ему пароль, подключил. Спасибо `@soon`. Оформите ответ? поставлю галку :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по сообщению ошибки, соединение происходит без SSL, хотя в конфигурационном файле разрешен доступ только через защищенные подключения:

```
hostssl all     all     192.168.255.170/32      md5
```

Цитата из [документации](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html):

> Запись `hostssl` позволяет установить шифрованное SSL соединение по протоколу TCP/IP.

Для того, чтобы разрешить не-SSL подключения, можно воспользоваться `host`:

> Запись `host` позволяет установить соединение по протоколу TCP/IP. Поддерживаются как незащищенные, так и шифрованные SSL подключения.

Также существует альнернатива `hostnossl`, которая, в противовес `hostssl` позволяет устанавливать **только** незащищенные соединения.